# Transparent GUI when running ABAQUS CAE

Tags: display, intel-graphics, gui

I am running the ABAQUS CAE (6-14.1) on a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The application launches but I get the following list of errors.

```
*******Begin: List of Error Messages**********

X Error: code 2 major 154 minor 3: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation).
X Error: code 169 major 154 minor 5: GLXBadContext.
X Error: code 0 major 154 minor 26: 0.
X Error: code 169 major 154 minor 4: GLXBadContext.

Warning: Your system need to be reconfigured to allow OpenGL rendering to a pixmap or you will only be able to print to raster formats.

*******End: List of Error Messages**********
```

As mentioned above the ABAQUS CAE GUI does launch but results in a "translucent" screen and I cannot make out the text or graphics (See below screenshot), and hence cannot work with the software.

[image]

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit)
Hardware: Dell Inspiron N5110;
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz x4; 
Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 card; Intel Sandybridge Mobile
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I get rid of the transparency problem when I execute the following command on my laptop (I found the solution here (no. 3 in the list): http://imechanica.org/node/13804))

```
env XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 /home/XXXXXX/ABAQUS/6.14-1/code/bin/abq6141 cae
```

ABAQUS CAE succesfully opens, but I run into a new problem! I see two "floaters" on top my CAE GUI ([please attached file "UpdatedScreenshot_ABAQUS_CAE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0cj5.png)). These "floaters" are residual graphics from the underlying terminal window (they include the text "out of range for" in the attached figure). I would like to get rid of these "residual graphics" since they are in the way and interfere with my work on the GUI.

I also see same errors on the Linux terminal window as before. I am also copying and pasting the error messages again below for clarity.

```
X Error: code 2 major 154 minor 3: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation).
X Error: code 169 major 154 minor 5: GLXBadContext.
X Error: code 0 major 154 minor 26: 0.
X Error: code 169 major 154 minor 4: GLXBadContext.

Warning: Your system need to be reconfigured to allow OpenGL
rendering to a pixmap or you will only be able to print to
raster formats.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by starting abaqus from gnome session classic:
-install  gnome classic:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

-log out

-log in with Classic GNOME Flashback session as explained [here](http://www.debugpoint.com/2016/04/install-classic-gnome-flashback-in-ubuntu-16-04-replacing-unity/)

-launch abaqus

Then you normaly get a normal abaqus windows with neither transparency nor phantom windows problem.

Answer (score 0):

The two floaters are linked to the toolbars. Just add the two non-selected toolbars from "View -> Toolbars" and the problem should go away.